# Strategy background for exact entry and exit price

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to just simply highlight my strategy with adding a background in the range of entry and exit price. I tried to do it with fill, bgcolor, plot, etc but I don't really find how can I get the entry and exit prices.

I'm using a limit order to the entry and stop loss/take profit orders for exit.
My code looks like this:

```
if (longCondition)
    longEnterPrice = high + (high * 0.0011)
    strategy.entry("LONG_POS_ID", strategy.long, stop = longEnterPrice, limit = longEnterPrice, comment = "LONG_ENTRY")
    strategy.exit("LONG_POS_ID", limit = longEnterPrice + longEnterPrice * 0.01, stop = longEnterPrice - longEnterPrice * 0.01, comment = "LONG_EXIT")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try this friend

```
longEnterPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)

limit = longEnterPrice + longEnterPrice * 0.01

stop = longEnterPrice - longEnterPrice * 0.01

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("LONG_POS_ID", strategy.long, comment = "LONG_ENTRY")

strategy.exit("LONG_POS_ID", limit = limit, stop = stop, comment = "LONG_EXIT", when = strategy.position_size > 0)

p1 = plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? limit : na,          color= color.green  , style=plot.style_linebr)
p2 = plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? longEnterPrice : na, color=color.gray    , style=plot.style_linebr)
p3 = plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? stop : na,           color=color.red     , style=plot.style_linebr)

fill(p1,p2, color= color.new(color.green, 80))
fill(p2,p3, color= color.new(color.red,   80))
```

cheers and best of luck with your coding

Comment: great, thanks a lot!